# How To Change Url Doing Some Changes in Search Form

Tags: search, forms

How can url show like i want or prefix text in search query

```
form class="search" action="/search">


input type="hidden" name="type" value="product" />

input type="text" placeholder="Search Your Model Here.." name="q" value="{{ search.terms | escape }} iphone 6 photo cover " size="45" />
input type="submit" value="Search" value="product" />
input type="hidden" name="title" value="Photo" />
</form>
```

now i am getting this url

https://paybydaddy.com/search?type=product&q=+iphone+6&title=Photo

this is the code i place there i even use tag its not searching in tag i just want to add one word after search query

like  https://paybydaddy.com/search?type=product&q=+iphone+6=Photo . just want to add =photo after search query how can i change something in this code for that please help

Comment: Some One Can Solve This Problem Please??

Answer (score 1):

The character `=` in a URL is used to separate a name from a value (this is how the query arguments are defined) and it cannot be used as such in your example unless you URL encode it.

Comment: thats what i want know how can i edit code to get desire result

Comment: Like What i need to change in code